# Make a modal in R shiny that only executes Rscript if you press "OK"

Tags: r, web-applications, shiny, modal-dialog

My Rshiny app currently takes in user input and when you press submit it writes these inputs to an external csv file, however in terms of error checking I would like a pop up to appear which states "You have inputted x, y, z, are you happy with this?", and if the user selects OK then (and only then) it runs the code to write to csv. If they press "Cancel", the external csv is unchanged. Any help with packages to do this? I've looked at shinyjs and shinyalert but I can't seem to find out how to do this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
          shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
          sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                   numericInput(inputId = "num1", "Numeric 1", value = 10),
                   numericInput(inputId = "num2", "Numeric 2", value = 20),
                   actionButton("go", "GO")
           ),
mainPanel()
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
       observe({
           #The element will be enabled if the condition evaluates to TRUE
           shinyjs::toggleState("go",condition = isTruthy(input$num1) && isTruthy(input$num2))
         })

v1_r<- reactiveValues()

observeEvent(input$go, {

    v1_r$colm1 <-  input$num1
    v1_r$colm2 <- input$num2

    v1_r$df_check <-  data.frame("Variables"=c("Input one","Input two"),"Values"=c(v1_r$colm1,v1_r$colm2))

    v1_r$review = datatable(rownames=FALSE,selection = "none",options = list(dom='t',pageLength = nrow(v1_r$df_check), autoWidth = FALSE,columnDefs = list(list(width = '20%', targets = c(1)),list(className = 'dt-center',targets=c(1)))),v1_r$df_check)

     showModal(
         modalDialog(
  footer = tagList(modalButton("Update record"),actionButton("click",label="Proceed")),
  strong(em("Inputs Entered")),
  p("Please double check the inputs entered before you proceed"),
  DT::renderDataTable({v1_r$review})
     )
  )
 })


   observeEvent(input$click, {

   #Save to CSV file

    shinyjs::reset("num1");shinyjs::reset("num2")
    removeModal()

  })

 }

 shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Here how I solve this issue, I hope it helps ;)

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for. However, when I adapted this for my code I got this error "Warning: Error in data.frame: arguments imply differing number of rows: 5, 4" - is this because my user inputs are 5 different selectInputs with a different number of options each? Or is it for some other reason do you think? Would you know how to solve this?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Usually I get this error when there is a different between number of rows in the data frame, and as error message says "Variables" has 5 rows but  "Values" has only 4 rows. So make sure inputs for "Values" are indeed 5 valid inputs.

Comment: But I don't know how your selectInputs look like so it's hard to tell how I would solve this issue, if multiple choices allowed then maybe better to use print  for example. Finally as always, small reproducible example will be helpful.